# Sonarqube incremental analysis failing

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Sonarqube full analysis mode is working fine, but incremental analysis is failing with below error:- [image]

Main error is:-
Fail to download [http://IP:9000/sonar/batch_bootstrap/db?project=project_name], Response code: 500

I have 2 projects, JS and Java project.

For JS project, the incremental analysis is working, but it's not working for java code's analysis.

Sonarqube version - 4.5.2
Java version - 8
Mysql - 5.7

**Update 1**

Full analysis has detected 500 000 issues. So, is it possible that incremental analysis is failing because of scaling issues.

Moreover, full analysis did have some ERRORs in console like class not found, and ignored certain files. Still, analysis ultimately succeeded. So, could this be the reason that incremental analysis is failing?

Comment: Hi, An HTTP code 500 usually mean a server side error. Please have a look at server side logs for more details.

Comment: Sonar logs suggest that error is "java heap space out of memory error". My ram is 16 GB. I tried to increase heap space in sonar -runner. bat file by adding "set SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Xmx3096m".     I also increased value of XX:MaxPermSize and Xmx. Still, facing the issue.

Comment: If OOM is on server side then you should increase memory of the server (see sonar.properties file). SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is for the scanner.

Comment: I have made server side changes also without any success like wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m, wrapper.java.additional.6=-Xmx5120M